# SharePoint 2013: Latest version of file not showing latest changes

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document, versioning

There is a file called xyz.xlsx with version 1 in a document library in SharePoint 2013.

a user checks out this xyz file, opens it in excel, makes some changes, saves and checks the file back in.  This xyz file now has the version 2.

However later on, when other people open this same file,  they can only see the old changes. They are not able to view the latest changes of this file with version 2.

It has been noticed that this problem is only happening to this file and to whenever this user makes changes to this file.

I double checked and verified that 'Require content approval for submitted items' is set to No.  User does not have office upload center on their computer.  Tried deleting the cache in excel. None of these fixed the issue.

Why is this happening? Could this be a caching issue? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file is checked out, if so, try to check in to see if it works normally.

Or re-upload a copy of this document to this library or other libraries to see if it works properly.

Reference：
[Check out, check in, or discard changes to files in a SharePoint library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/check-out-check-in-or-discard-changes-to-files-in-a-sharepoint-library-7e2c12a9-a874-4393-9511-1378a700f6de)

Comment: The file is already checked in.

Re-uploading a copy under a different name works (shows the latest changes). The workaround I use is re-uploading the file under a different name, deleting the original and renaming the duplicate to the original. Is there a permanent solution to this?